# Grails + GWT - using the same Date Format

Tags: gwt, grails, localization, client

I am developing an app using `Grails` and `GWT` for a client side.
I want to use the same `date format` both on the client side and on the server side (preferably defined in one file).

So far i've understood that Grails got it's own mechanism for internationalization (`grails-app/i18n`). I know i can access these messages from any server code using app context.
I can also access any resource file inside `web-app` directory.

For the client side, i can use `ConstantsWithLookup` interface and `GWT.Create(...)` to get an instance of it.

But, i still haven't found good solution to integrate these two together, so i have `date format` defined in one place. Any ideas or tips?

Thanks,
Sergey

Comment: After googling for a while, i found this - http://www.cacoethes.co.uk/blog/groovyandgrails/internationalising-your-grails-gwt-applications
I am going to investigate, maybe my question is well described there (i hope :)

Comment: This may help: http://groups.google.com/group/grails-gwt/browse_thread/thread/6e1bcac2844f062

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into Grails more, i came to a solution.
I've put constant into `.properties` file under `grails-app/i18n`.
Then, i hook to `eventCompileEnd` and i copy resources from `grails-app/i18n` to specific package in `target\generated-sources`.
After this step is completed, i generate google I18N interfaces using copied property files.
I've put this functionality to separate plugin.

**_Events.groovy**:

```
includeTargets << new File("${myPluginDir}/scripts/_MyInternal.groovy")

eventCompileEnd = {
  internalCopyMessageResources();
}

eventCopyMessageResourcesEnd = {
  generateI18NInterface();
}
```

Now it is possible to access localized data from server side and from client side.